# Project 'production' could not be found in workspace, when i build the angular project for production

Tags: angular, build, production

I am new to Angular. I use this command `ng build --target=production --base-href /`, and here is the error that produces while build angular project for production.

```
Project 'production' could not be found in workspace.
Error: Project 'production' could not be found in workspace.
    at Workspace.getProject (/home/linux/Downloads/weather/node_modules/@angular-devkit/core/src/workspace/workspace.js:83:19)
    at Architect.getBuilderConfiguration (/home/linux/Downloads/weather/node_modules/@angular-devkit/architect/src/architect.js:96:41)
    at MergeMapSubscriber._loadWorkspaceAndArchitect.pipe.operators_1.concatMap [as project] (/home/linux/Downloads/weather/node_modules/@angular/cli/models/architect-command.js:77:55)
    at MergeMapSubscriber._tryNext (/home/linux/Downloads/weather/node_modules/rxjs/internal/operators/mergeMap.js:122:27)
    at MergeMapSubscriber._next (/home/linux/Downloads/weather/node_modules/rxjs/internal/operators/mergeMap.js:112:18)
    at MergeMapSubscriber.Subscriber.next (/home/linux/Downloads/weather/node_modules/rxjs/internal/Subscriber.js:103:18)
    at TapSubscriber._next (/home/linux/Downloads/weather/node_modules/rxjs/internal/operators/tap.js:109:26)
    at TapSubscriber.Subscriber.next (/home/linux/Downloads/weather/node_modules/rxjs/internal/Subscriber.js:103:18)
    at MergeMapSubscriber.notifyNext (/home/linux/Downloads/weather/node_modules/rxjs/internal/operators/mergeMap.js:141:26)
    at InnerSubscriber._next (/home/linux/Downloads/weather/node_modules/rxjs/internal/InnerSubscriber.js:30:21)
```

Comment: Do you get the same error when you run `ng build --prod`, or `ng build --prod --base-href /`?

Comment: thanks R. Richards I have tried "ng build --prod --base-href /" and project successfully build.but Can you please tell the difference between the command I'm writing and yours.

Comment: It would seem that you cannot run the build with just a `target`, you have to include an `environment`, too. [This](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/wiki/build#build-targets-and-environment-files) may be of some help to you. The docs don't *explicitly* state that you have to include both options, but it does read that way.

Answer (score 5):

It happened to me after upgrading from Angular 5 to Angular 6.

The solution is to replace in `angular.json`:

```
"prod": {
  "fileReplacements": [
    {
      "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
      "with": "src/environments/environment.prod.ts"
    }
  ]
},
```

with:

```
"production": {
  "fileReplacements": [
    {
      "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
      "with": "src/environments/environment.prod.ts"
    }
  ]
},
```

so basically it's just about renaming `prod` to `production`.